Domain of a function and simplification of fractions
I was working on the following exercise from a math book:
Question: what is the domain of the following real function:
$$ f(x)= \frac{x-1}{(x^2-1)(x^2-7x+10)} $$
Step 1, I develop:
$$ \frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x-5)} $$
Step 2, I simplify:
$$ \frac{1}{(x+1)(x-2)(x-5)} $$
And I find the following answer:
$$ D_f = \mathbb{R}_{\setminus\{-1,2,5\}} $$
I then checked the correction in the book which gives the following correct answer:
$$ D_f = \mathbb{R}_{\setminus\{-1,1,2,5\}} $$
But if $1$ must be excluded from the domain of $f$, it would lead to a contradiction. In effect, $1$ comes from the $(x - 1)$ that I simplified in step 2. If I exclude $1$ from the domain on that basis, I may also multiply the numerator and denominator by any real $a$ of the form $\frac{x+a}{x+a}$ and state that $a$ must be excluded from the domain of $f$. In consequence, we could no longer use fractions in algebra!
I feel my answer is correct and the book is incorrect, but since this is improbable in view of my level in math, I would like someone to confirm this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

In order to simplify the factor $x - 1$ from the numerator and the denominator you have (tacitly) assumed that $x\neq 1$. Hence the answer proposed by the book is correct, that is to say:
\begin{align*}
D_{f} = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{-1,1,2,5\}
\end{align*}

Thank you so much for your quick and clear answer. This clarifies an important point to me. As I understand it now, we cannot say that $\frac{x-1}{x-1} = 1$ but we can only say that $\frac{x-1}{x-1} = 1$ under the hypothesis that $x$ is not equal to $1$. Is this correct?

@DavidDoret You are welcome! Yes, that's correct.

@David f(x) isn't defined at x=1, but it does have a nice finite limit there. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtykEKwjAQRuF9T%5FEvZ%2DoETUS6yi1cC8UkEkgaSS2Mt5equ%5FfBS6QMD1IYWMYRRHpzP4z49zQqDrAn5iG0uu%5FmLJh4eJb2oiQIrQreNS%5FeuD1m9U4Q9V62ED0ZK3CCCwtSn2v0175FwaPnUPIS1695%2DAA0oCUP&lang=sage
